# Python generator yielding from nested non-generator function

Tags: python, generator, nested-function

This is a dumb example based on a more complex thing that I want to do:

```py
from typing import Generator


def f() -> Generator[list[int], None, None]:
    result = list()
    result.append(1)
    if len(result) == 2:
        yield result
        result = list()
    result.append(2)
    if len(result) == 2:
        yield result
        result = list()
    result.append(3)
    if len(result) == 2:
        yield result
        result = list()
    result.append(4)
    if len(result) == 2:
        yield result
        result = list()


print(list(f()))
```

The point here is that this bit is copied multiple times:

```py
    if len(result) == 2:
        yield result
        result = list()
```

Normally, I'd change it into something like this:

```py
from typing import Generator


def f() -> Generator[list[int], None, None]:
    def add_one(value: int) -> None:
        nonlocal result
        result.append(value)
        if len(result) == 2:
            nonlocal_yield result
            result = list()

    result = list()
    add_one(1)
    add_one(2)
    add_one(3)
    add_one(4)


print(list(f()))
```

Obviously, `nonlocal_yield` is not a thing. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

I know that I can just create the full list of results, i.e., `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, and then either return it or `yield` individual 2-element sublists. Something like this:

```py
from typing import Generator


def f() -> list[list[int]]:
    def add_one(value: int) -> None:
        nonlocal current
        current.append(value)
        if len(current) == 2:
            result.append(current)
            current = list()

    result = list()
    current = list()
    add_one(1)
    add_one(2)
    add_one(3)
    add_one(4)
    return result


print(list(f()))
```

However, this beats the purpose of a generator. I'll go for it in absence of a better solution, but I'm curious if there is a "pure" generator way to do it.

Comment: Why not use a loop? `for value in 1, 2, 3, 4: dothestuff`

Comment: @KellyBundy, the actual code that I'm working on is more complex. It has two similar, but not identical loops doing something (similar between the loops, but not identical, so I cannot turn them into one loop), followed by this common code, plus one step between those loops with another copy of the common code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
def f() -> Generator[list[int], None, None]:
    def add_one(value: int) -> Generator[list[int], None, None]:
        nonlocal result
        result.append(value)
        if len(result) == 2:
            yield result
            result = list()

    result = list()
    yield from add_one(1)
    yield from add_one(2)
    yield from add_one(3)
    yield from add_one(4)
```

Comment: Sounds about right. Thank you. I'll ponder on it more and see if it fits my use case or I need to expand the example above. Side note: the return type of `add_one` should be the same as that of `f`, right?

Comment: @VedranŠego Right. I don't use type hints, forgot about that.

Comment: This works exactly as needed. Thank you.